# how to keep moved up element in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function inview(el) {
 var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
 return (rect.top >= 30 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight);
}

$('.story').on('click', function(){
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});

$('.btndown').on('click', function(){
  $('.act').insertAfter($('.act').next('.story'));
  var el = $('.act');
  if(!inview(el[0])){
   let a = $('.act').offset().top;
   $(document).scrollTop(a - 120);
 }
});


$('.btnup').on('click', function(){
  $('.act').insertBefore($('.act').prev('.story'));
  var el = $('.act');
  if(!inview(el[0])){
   let a = $('.act').offset().top;
   $(document).scrollTop('???');
 }
});
```

```css
.nav{
position:fixed;
left:0; top:0; width:100%; background:gold;
}

.panelb{
width:50%; margin:120px auto 0 auto; border:2px solid #ddd;
}

.story{
cursor:pointer; background:lightgreen; border-top:2px solid #ddd; border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;
}

.act{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='nav'>
<button class='btnup'>UP</button>
<button class='btndown'>DOWN</button>
</div>

<div class='panelb'>
<div class='story'>lorem 1</div>
<div class='story'>lorem 2<br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 3<br><br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 4<br><br><br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 5<br><br><br><br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 6<br><br><br><br><br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 7<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 8<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
<div class='story'>lorem 9<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

So click on `lorem 3` to make it active.

Then click on `btndown` several times to see it in action - move down the `act` and keep it in viewport.

Now click on `btnup`. I simply don't know what to write inside brackets on `$(document).scrollTop('???');` line - to keep the moved element visible.

I tried many combinations with `scrollTop`, `offset().top`, `el.height()`... without success.

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making this more difficult than it need be.

Since your up and down functions are nearly identical, they should be combined into a single function that is triggered when either button is pressed and then, you just need a simple `if/else` to determine which was pressed and do the unique operations.

With regard to your question, the DOM [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method handles it as shown below. Your `inView` function may no longer even be necessary.

```js
$('.story').on('click', function(){
  $('.act').removeClass('act');
  $(this).addClass('act');
});

// Just one function for both buttons
$('.btndown, .btnup').on('click', function(){
    var el = $('.act'); 
    // Determine which button was clicked by what class it has
    if(this.classList.contains("btndown")){
      // If there is a next element...
      if(el.next(".story")){
        el.insertAfter(el.next('.story'));   // Move down
      }
    } else {
      // If there is a previous element...
      if(el.prev(".story")){
        el.insertBefore(el.prev('.story'));  // Move up
      }
    }
    // Either way, keep the moved element in view
    el[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"}); 
});
```

```css
.nav{ position:fixed; left:0; top:0; width:100%; background:gold; }

.panelb{ width:50%; margin:120px auto 0 auto; border:2px solid #ddd; }

.story{
  cursor:pointer; background:lightgreen; border-top:2px solid #ddd; 
  border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;
}

.act{ background:gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='nav'>
  <button class='btnup'>UP</button>
  <button class='btndown'>DOWN</button>
</div>

<div class='panelb'>
  <div class='story'>lorem 1</div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 2<br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 3<br><br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 4<br><br><br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 5<br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 6<br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 7<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 8<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class='story'>lorem 9<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. `scrollIntoView()` is a news for me. Is there any official place on web where one can see all existing js functions, pls?

Comment: and just a note - in your snippet entire page is scrolled, not just snippet area, I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: @puerto You're welcome. If this helped, please up vote it. If it answered your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the question. Now, when you ask where you can go to see "all existing functions", I'm not quite sure what you mean. `scrollIntoView()` is part of the DOM API, which you can explore [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: @puerto As for what gets scrolled, the only reason the whole page scrolls in my example is because the elements that are getting scrolled are in the normal document flow. If the `.panel` element that contained them all had it `position` set so that it was not in the normal flow, then it would scroll independent of the rest of the document. Also, in your example, the entire document is scrolled as well.

Comment: you're so... excellent. thanks again. voted and accepted, of course.